# SQL: Replacing dates contained within a text string

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012. I work with medical records and need to de-identify reports. The reports are structured in a table with columns Report_Date, Report_Subject, Report_Text, etc... The string I need to update is in report_text and there are ~700,000 records.

So if I have:

```
"patient had an EKG on 04/09/2012"
```

I need to replace that with:

```
"patient had an EKG on [DEIDENTIFIED]"
```

I tried

```
UPDATE table 
SET Report_Text = REPLACE(Report_Text, '____/___/____', '[DEIDENTIFED]')
```

because I need to replace anything in there that looks like a date, and it runs but doesn't actually replace anything, because apparently I can't use the _ wildcard in this command.

Any recommendations on this? Advance thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX` to find the location of Date and then use `SUBSTRING` and `REPLACE` to replace the dates.

Since there may be multiple dates in the Text you have to run a while loop to replace all the dates.

Below sql will work for all dates in the form of MM/DD/YYYY

```
WHILE EXISTS( SELECT 1  FROM  dbo.MyTable WHERE  PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Report_Text) > 0 )

BEGIN

    UPDATE  t
    SET     Report_Text = REPLACE(Report_Text, DateToBeReplaced, '[DEIDENTIFIED]')
    FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                        SUBSTRING(Report_Text,PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Report_Text), 10) AS DateToBeReplaced
              FROM      dbo.MyTable AS a
              WHERE     PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',Report_Text) > 0
            ) AS t

END
```

I have tested the above sql on a dummy table with few rows.I don't know how it will scale for your data but recommend you to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, assume that a number represents an identifying element in the string so look for the position of the first number in the string and the position of the last number in the string.   Not sure if this will apply to your entire set of records but here is the code ...

I created two test strings ... the one you supplied and one with the date at the beginning of the string.

```
Declare @tstString varchar(100)
Set @tstString = 'patient had an EKG on 04/09/2012'
Set @tstString = '04/09/2012 EKG for patient'

Select @tstString
-- Calculate 1st Occurrence of a Number
,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@tstString)
-- Calculate last Occurrence of a Number
,LEN(@tstString) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(@tstString))

,CASE
    -- No numbers in the string, return the string
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@tstString) = 0 THEN @tstString

    -- Number is the first character to find the last position and remove front
    WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@tstString) = 1 THEN 
        CONCAT('[DEIDENTIFIED]',SUBSTRING(@tstString, LEN(@tstString)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(@tstString))+2,LEN(@tstString)))

    -- Just select string up to the first number
    ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@tstString,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@tstString)-1),'[DEIDENTIFIED]')
    END AS 'newString'
```

As you can see, this is messy in SQL.
I would rather achieve this with a parser service and move the data with SSIS and call the service.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner! Thank you very much for helping. To be sure this solution will work throughout my table: the text in this document varies a lot; riddled with dates that could be located anywhere within the text and usually not in any predictable context. Will this solution find any date anywhere and replace it? or does my declare need to be as specific as your example here? Thank you again.

Comment: Put some examples into the @tstString variable and you will see the results.   It will indeed find the date but I think it will then truncate the string and add the [DEIDENTIFIED].   So it will find the date but not show the entire text.   You will have to add another WHEN clause to handle when the date appears in the middle.